# CSS3 animation/transform not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am using Jquery and CSS3 to animate a couple of elements (call + send us a message button), having them fade-in and upwards when they become visible.

The animation works fine on IE10+, but doesn't on Chrome. The Jquery also seems to add the styles correctly when I inspect the element in the developer console.

Here is the CSS:

```
.come-in {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(150px);
   transform: translateY(150px);
  animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
}
.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
.already-visible {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: none;
  -webkit-animation: none;
}
@keyframes come-in {
  to { transform: translateY(0); 
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0); 
  }
}
```

The Jquery:

```
$.fn.visible = function(partial) {

    var $t            = $(this),
        $w            = $(window),
        viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
        viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
        _top          = $t.offset().top,
        _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
        compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
        compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

};

(jQuery);


$(window).scroll(function(event) {

    $(".button").each(function(i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
            el.addClass("come-in"); 
        } 
    });

});
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
 <div class="columns five button">
    <h2 class="no-margin padding-small"><img src="images/phone16.png" alt=""/>Call 128 3778 9237</h2>
    <div class="clear"><!-- ClearFix --></div>
</div>
<div class="columns five center button">
    <h2 class="no-margin padding-small"><img src="images/chat81.png" alt="" />Send us a message</h2>
    <div class="clear"><!-- ClearFix --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When it works in IE but not in Chrome, you know you have a syntax error.

Comment: There's no syntax error in JS console in the dev tools, and nothing sticks out in the CSS either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes come-in {
  to { transform: translateY(0); 
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0); 
  }
}
```

It will be [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation) without prefix in Chrome 40.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed adding the -webkit- prefix there.